# Multiple rows to 1 row in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have these following documents:

```
{ _id: 1,
  Field1: Visit1,
  Field2: ["I have headache"],
  Field3: "CC"
},
{ _id: 2,
  Field1: "Visit1",
  Field2: ["2 days PTC, patient experiences sharp stabbing pain"],
  Field3: "HPI"
}
```

What I want to achieve is this kind of output:

```
{
  _id:1,
  Field1: "Visit1",
  Field2: ["I have headache"],
  Field3: ["2 days PTC, patient experiences sharp stabbing pain"]
}
```

How can I achieve this output using the MongoDB query aggregation. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you forgot to list your question in the post. You have the document, what's the next action to the expected result, what's the expected result and what's your attempt.

Comment: Yeah I apologize for this, I've now updated the question. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: Need to further explain your expected data for better understanding. In what situation that combine the document into 1, certain document (with link/relationship) or all documents? Why the second input document's `Field2` become the `Field3` in the expected result?